# jquery DataTables using Object.keys .map strangely returning old datables version columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been using datatables jquery pluging for years
I am seeing a very strange bug / occurrence
when setting up dynamic columns and data 
see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scriptgurus/6da21tyn/

it seems when datatables latest ver 1.10.13 is plugged in 
using :

```
var cols = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(key) {
    return {title: key, data: key};
});
```

to return just all keys (for generating the columns:) from the data (see jsfiddle ex) it will return the new data:key and also the old legacy ver .. mData, and sTitle..

very weird .. anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to datatables doc https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data:

> Older versions of DataTables (1.9-) used a different set of parameters
>   to send and receive from the server. As such scripts which are written
>   for DataTables 1.10+ will not be able to function with DataTables
>   1.9-. However, DataTables 1.10 does have a compatibility mode for scripts written for 1.9-. This compatibility mode is triggered by use
>   of the old sAjaxSource parameter (rather than the new ajax parameter)
>   or by setting $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;

So mData and sTitle is there to work with older datatable settings with new library version.

Comment: thanks but adding: $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = false; still adding unwanted old keys sTitle, mData etc automatically .. strange it hooks in  on any reference to keys data.. title and adds legacy keys .. I even tried to delete keys after .

Comment: This is a Real problem if you are defining or mapping a different array/object to be used in your script.. datatables will always add its legacy keys to any object having keys:  "data" .. "title", "render"

Comment: Currently you cannot turn them off. If you're using jQuery DataTables 1.10 but server-side processing parameters are from previous version of DataTables 1.9 then $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true before DataTables initialization code will force jQuery DataTables use old scheme.

Comment: take a look at the jsfiddle again - I am using dt 1.10 and invoking it with latest prams--  I am Not using  legacy server-side processing or any legacy parameters--> var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   data: data,
   columns: cols,
      });